# Cannot resolve all parameters for class in Angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm just learning Ionic and Angular so I was following this simple recording tutorial. However, it gives me an error like so:

> Can't resolve all parameters for HomePage in
> /ionic/recording-play/src/app/home/home.page.ts: ([object Object], ?, ?, [object Object])

Below is my import

```
import { NavController, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Media, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file';
```

and my constructor

```
constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    // @Inject(forwardRef(() => Media)) private media: Media,
    // @Inject(forwardRef(() => File)) private file: File,
    private media: Media,
    private file: File,
    public platform: Platform
    ) {}
```

As you can see, I have tried the inject method and it did not work so, could anyone please help me and thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Can you try to run again after removing the commented code in the constructor?

Comment: @PardeepJain it runs but it gives me black screen. The error I stated in the title is only in vscode so now I'm not sure if that is even a legitimate error.

Comment: Great, you can ignore that. So now can you check your console if there is another error showing?